# Read from file and find max c#

Tags: c#, struct, procedures

I have started learning c# just over 3 months so for homework I have an exercise where i have to read from a text file with 50 names and marks. I have to find the name with the highest mark display it and save the result to a text file.This is what I have come up with.

```
namespace FINAL
{
    class Program
    {


       public  static string [] parts;

        struct StudentDetails
        {

            public string name; 
            public string surname; 
        };
        struct CourseWorkResults
        { public int mark;
        };
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {  

           string [] Lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"F:\FINAL\StudentExamMarks.txt");
            foreach (string line in Lines)
           {
               string[] parts = line.Split();
            }
           StudentDetails[] Student = new StudentDetails[50];
            CourseWorkResults[] Results = new CourseWorkResults[50];


            GetName( ref Student ,ref parts );
            FindMark ( ref Results , parts);
            FindMax (ref Results);

        }
        static void GetName(ref StudentDetails[]Student,  ref string[] parts)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Student.Length; i++ )
            {
                Student[i].name = parts[0];
                Student[i].surname = parts[1];
            }
        }
       static void FindMark ( ref CourseWorkResults[]Results, string [] parts )
        {
            for (int i=0; i< Results.Length;i++)
            {
                Results[i].mark = Convert.ToInt16(parts[2]);
            }

        }
       static void FindMax( ref CourseWorkResults[]Results)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Results.Length; i++)
            {
                int max = 0;
                max = Results[2].mark;
                if (Results[i].mark > max)
                {
                    max = Results[i].mark;
                }
            }
        }
       static void DisplayResults( ref CourseWorkResults[]Results, StudentDetails[]Student, int max)

           {

        Console.WriteLine(" The student with the highest score is {0} {1} :{2}", Student[0].name, Student[1].surname, max);
           } 
   }
 }
```

My problem is the GetName procedure , I can't pass by reference parts. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that a `struct` is an immutable value type. So when you write :

```
 Student[i].name = parts[0];
```

You are just trying to modify a local a copy of `Student[i]`. Actually, each time you trying to access `Student[i]`, it will always return a copied value instead the *instance* on the list.

A workaround is  to have `StudentDetails` as `class` instead of `struct`

```
  class StudentDetails
  {
      public string name; 
      public string surname; 
  };
```

The issue applies also for `CourseWorkResults` struct.

In addition, as arrays are already reference in .NET. You don't really need to pass it as reference unless you want it to reference another object. I.e, this :

```
    static void GetName(StudentDetails[]Student,  ref string[] parts)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Student.Length; i++ )
        {
            Student[i].name = parts[0];
            Student[i].surname = parts[1];
        }
    }
```

will work as

```
    static void GetName(ref StudentDetails[]Student,  ref string[] parts)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Student.Length; i++ )
        {
            Student[i].name = parts[0];
            Student[i].surname = parts[1];
        }
    }
```

Unless you add something like this:

```
    static void GetName(ref StudentDetails[]Student,  ref string[] parts)
    {
        Student = anotherStudentArray ; // Here the ref param is really needed as you want to reassign Student to a new array instance

        for (int i = 0; i < Student.Length; i++ )
        {
            Student[i].name = parts[0];
            Student[i].surname = parts[1];
        }
    }
```

Comment: To add to this answer I would suggest reading up on POCO's https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd456872(v=vs.100).aspx and use the POCO as a data store.